# How to solve Access Denied error on AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to run this command on my AWS cli:

```
aws s3 ls s3://BUCKET_NAME
```

But it throws this error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

Here are my authorizations, settings and steps I have tried:

I'm an IAM user with administrator privileges.
I've set this policy on my IAM account:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "s3permission",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've set this policy on the `BUCKET_NAME`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "s3permission",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/MY_USERNAME"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've run `aws configure` and configured my profile.
We're not using VPN.

But it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Add this `"arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME",` to your iam role for your user. Also, make sure you are using the right profile when using the aws cli.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the right profile. May this be because of the `Block Public Access` is enabled?

Comment: with the console, you able to list the objects?

Comment: @sundowatch, no it is not related to `Block Public Access`. Make sure you add the arn I mentioned above.

Comment: @brushtakopo, I added your suggestion. I think my problem is with MFA.

Comment: oh yes, most likely MFA, haven't thought about it since you didn't mention it.

Comment: Yes the problem is with MFA. I'll write the answer.